# 2005 Dodge Ram 1500slt 4.7 overheating

Tags: dodge, overheating, ram

My 2005 Dodge ram 1500 SLT four-door with the 4.7 Magnum has started overheating. Takes 10 or 20 minutes to reach the red zone. As a history of maintaining just above center gauge. I've replaced the thermostat and the radiator cap and can see no apparent leaks except when the radiator cap released excess pressure when hot. It does have 100,000 miles but otherwise runs good. What other items can I check?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you put the thermostat in the correct direction? Have you checked the lower radiator hose to ensure it isn't collapsing when the system is hot? Have you checked for coolant flow throughout the system?

Comment: I'm almost positive it was the correct direction, but I was not able to check for collapsing hose and it appears it might be the original based on the clamps

Comment: I didn't visit a local tire and service shop who checked it out as best they could even cooling system pressure test and they couldn't identify the problem. Suggested a full service shop or dealer.

Comment: When completely warmed up, the bottom hose, which is the intake side from the radiator, can collapse when stressed, which can cause things to overheat. It's the reason there are wire springs (sort of springs) put into the hoses to prevent this. The springs can rust away or deteriorate. If the hose isn't collapsing, you need to check the water pump and ensure there is flow from it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I did get a new cap and a different thermostat on the chance I damaged the first one. It's been a long hot stress full day. But it seems to be maintaining something mid range on the drive home. I will likely get new hoses soon too, I'm thinking they are old enough. Fingers crossed for now.